# Pygame, trouble with collisions

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection, collision

I have been trying to create a game form scratch in Python using Pygame. I followed a tutorial for the most part and have hit a wall. The game is a simple platformer and I'm having trouble adding in collisions. I have looked at many other examples but cant seem to find where abouts to add in the `pygame.sprite.collide_rect` command and how to get it to stop the players y velocity so that he stops ontop of a platform. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

The code

```
import random 
import pygame as pg
pg.init()




icon = pg.image.load("soldier.png")
pg.display.set_icon(icon)
backgroundimage = pg.image.load("background.png")


FPS = 50
Width = 512
Height = 384
Red = (255, 0, 0)
#vec = pg.math.Vector2

class platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load("plat.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y



class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load("Spaceman.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (Width / 2, Height / 2)
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0
        #self.pos = vec(Width / 2, Height / 2)
        self.acc = 0.2


    def update(self):
        self.vy = self.vy + self.acc
        self.vx = 0
        #self.acc = vec(0, 0.5)
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
            while self.vy > 0:
             self.vy = -5 + self.acc
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.vx = -5
            self.image = pg.image.load("Spaceman2.png")
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.vx = 5
            self.image = pg.image.load("Spaceman.png")



        self.rect.x += self.vx
        self.rect.y += self.vy
        if self.rect.left > Width:
            self.rect.right = 0
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.rect.left = Width
    






class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        pg.mixer.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((Width,Height))
        pg.display.set_caption("OH NOOOO")
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.running = True

    def new(self):
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.platforms = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.soldier = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player()
        self.all_sprites.add(self.player)
        self.soldier.add(self.player)
        p1 = platform(200, 200)
        self.all_sprites.add(p1)
        self.platforms.add(p1)
        self.run()


    def run(self):
   
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()
       

    def update(self):
         self.screen.blit(backgroundimage,[0,0])

         self.all_sprites.update()

    def events(self):
         for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                self.running = False

    def draw(self):
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)


        pg.display.flip()
    


    def show_start_screen(self):
        pass


    def show_go_screen(self):
        pass
                  

g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while g.running:

    g.new()
    g.show_go_screen()

pg.quit()
```

This is all of the code so far and I've made three groups within this code; all_sprites, soldier and platforms but cant figure out how to make soldier and platforms groups collide. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: What is the question? Do you not know how to detect a collision? Use [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). What do you want to do when you detect a collision?

Comment: Sorry , what I'm trying to ask is how to detect a collision between the platform group and the soldier group in order to have the soldier land on the platform instead of falling through it. I don't fully understand how collision detection works and where and how to format the pygame.sprite.groupcollide().

Comment: So your question goes way beyond simple collision detection. It is a question about game physic.

Comment: I think I might be able to figure out stopping a players velocity once a collision has been detected yet I still don't know how to detect a collision.

Comment: I told you to use [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). What do you not understand about it? It is well documented. Just follow the link and read the documentation. Try  `if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.soldier, self.platforms, False, Fasle): print("hit")`

Comment: Thanks! this should work great, sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) to detect the collision of [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects in 2 separate [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)s:

```py
if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.soldier, self.platforms, False, Fasle):
    print("hit")
```